# execute another unix command from shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, vi

I have a shell script which goes to certain directory and delete all sub directories present under parent directory (/home/nandus/tryd). After deletion, script has to show parent directory structure post delete operation, just to show to end user that all sub directories are deleted.

I tried to use exec for rm -rf *, but its not returning to main program and its not performing remaining steps in the shell script.

Can you please let me know how to do this shell script?

```
  cd /home/nandus/tryd
  exec rm -rf *
  echo '/home/nandus/tryd directory structure post delete'
  cd /home/nandis/tryd
  exec pwd
  exec ls -ltr
```

**strong text**

Comment: why are you passing everything through `exec`? You should be calling them directlry `rm -rvf *`, `pwd`, etc

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Is it applicable even to kill a process if I know pid like  kill -9 <pid> from shell script?

Comment: Just delete the silly `exec`..... The second `cd` is redundant. BTW: The working directory is also stored in the variable `PWD`.

Comment: Yes if you know the pid of the process you can `kill` it. Although realistically with commands like `echo` and `ls` they will be executed WAY to fast for it to be practical to try and manually kill them.

Answer (score 0):

as bash , exec **replacing** the current program with a new one . not forking  childs.

Open a bash shell , try the following

```
mkdir tmp && cd tmp
exec sleep 10
```

> After directory build and set , Bash session replaced with sleep 10 which exit automatically after 10sec

also

```
mkdir tmp && cd tmp
exec pwd && sleep 10
```

> Bash session replaced with pwd , which not designed to keep session and execute the "&&" , so sleep never reached.